# diff between boolean res=a==b and boolean res=(a==b)

Tags: java

can any one explain ?

```
String a=new String("srihari");
String b=new String("srihari");

boolean res1=(a==b); // reference check
System.out.println(r); // true

boolean res2=a==b;   // object check (diff object)
System.out.println(res);  // false
```

why this diff b/w `res1` and `res2` ,

`res2=a==b` how here two objects  and `res1=(a==b)` why reference here

Comment: you don't print `res1`.

Comment: Nor `res2`, for that matter.

Comment: There's no difference between doing `(a==b)` and `a==b` here. What are you really asking ? You may notice your code doesn't make sense to us, as you're printing out `r` and `res` , which are variables we cannot see.

Comment: No difference both **boolean res1=(a==b);** and **boolean res2=a==b;** are checking Object and both will print **false**.

Answer (score 4):

You are not using the proper variables:

```
String a=new String("srihari");
String b=new String("srihari");

boolean res1=(a==b);
System.out.println(res1); // false

boolean res2=a==b;
System.out.println(res2);  // false
```

As for the explanations, you do a reference check both time, and it it `false`. The evaluation is done before the affectation so both your tests are in fact the same.

They other way around makes no sense, you cannot assign a `String` to a `boolean` and then check if the result has the same reference than another `String`.

Answer (score 0):

Both `println` print `false` because `a` is not equal to `b` in reference mean.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that the code sample provided is not the original one which caused the problem for the OP (due to variable issues pointed out by others) but it is indeed possible for `==` between `String` references to return `true` (which may be what the OP experienced).

```
public class Main
{
     public static void main(String... args)
     {
         String s1 = "srihari";
         String s2 = "srihari";
         System.out.println(s1 == s2); //true
     }
}
```

The reason for this is that Java sees the string literal `"srihari"` twice and assigns both to the same interned string instance as an optimisation.

Of course I'm guessing at what the OP originally intended. I may be off track